# PHP Class diagram that generates the code

Tags: php, class-diagram

Im looking for an application with the following funcionalities:

- Creates class diagrams
- Generates code of the structure that you just diagram

The class structure in PHP.

Thanks alot in advance, i'm sorry if my writing isn't that great english is not my language.

Comment: Might want to also specify what operating system it should work on

Answer (score 2):

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is a free UML modeler and supports PHP5 code generation.

Comment: Thanks alot ill be giving reviews of both

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect costs $135.00 + $45.00 per each 12 months (USD)

I think they offer a free 12 month trial.

It supports C++, Java, VB.NET, C#, **PHP**, Delphi and Visual Basic code generation

Comment: You might want to specify that in your question then

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite tools is PHPStorm. It is not free but it worth.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/working-with-diagrams.html

These people have also two applications for do that, they are not free but it seems they do what you want:

http://www.athtek.com/download.html#programming

This is an Open Project related to ArgoUML:

http://www.ohloh.net/p/codetodiagram